# Get first element with attribute in jQuery object, or first if none have attribute

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery object that contains multiple elements, and I want the first of those elements which has a specific data attribute... BUT if none of the elements has the attribute, I want the first element from the list.

The simple solution is to use `.filter("[data-attr]").first()` against the object for the attribute, and if that returns `.length == 0` then simply use `.first()`

```
var $list = $("li");
var $li = $list.filter("[data-attr]").first();
if ($li.length == 0) $li = $list.first();
```

I guess I could always do the following, but it seems very clunky...

```
var $list = $("li");
var $li = (($li = $list.filter("[data-attr]").first()).length == 1 ? $li : $list.first());
```

Is there a "nicer" way of doing this (without the use of external jQuery plugins)?

(This is not critical, and I'm happy to have the longer format of code... it's more for personal interest.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not many ways around it. It depends on how much you value the readability of your code.

What you could do, is to merge `$list.filter("[data-attr]")` and the `$list` and select the first element of the new list.

```
var $li = $.merge($list.filter('[data-attr]'), $list).first();
```

This would either return the first element with the `data-attr` (if one exists) or the first element of `$list`.

Comment: I like it, much nicer than either of my examples.  If nobody else comes up with anything that's even nicer, I'll accept your answer